# Is "Shaul" just a bad translation of "Saul"?

Tags: hebrew

Are "Shaul" and "Saul" the same name?

[image: translator]

Comment: Greek and Latin do not possess a (group of) letter(s) for *sh*, as Hebrew does.

Comment: I was talking about the Hebrew name, not the Greek one.

Comment: *Shaul* is indeed a Hebrew name, and the Hebrew alphabet does indeed have a letter denoting the sound *sh*. Greek and Latin, however, do not, and the New Testament was written in Greek, not in Hebrew. Hence, *Shaul* became *Saul*, which is not a translation, but a transliteration, just as *Jesus* is also a transliteration, this time of the Hebrew *Joshua*.

Comment: Jewish who lives in the west are given a western name or 'slave name' and also a Hebrew name.
https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/80495/jewish/Why-Do-I-Need-a-Hebrew-Name.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We pronounce is as Shaul in Israel and it starts with a "shin".
Saul is how it is pronounced in English.

The google translator is giving you the Hebrew word for Saul.
When you asked it for the meaning of Shaul the second time, it gave you the same Hebrew writing of the word... because there is no other.